# Parse Date In Spanish error

Tags: java, android, date, date-parsing

Hello Please help me out, I have gone through many questions but didn't get a solution.
Code

```
String localDate1="Miércoles, 04 Octubre 2017 12:00 PM";
Locale spanishLocale=new Locale("es", "ES");
SimpleDateFormat spanishLocale1=new SimpleDateFormat(getString(R.string.jom_events_date_input_format_12_hrs),spanishLocale);
String dateInSpanish=spanishLocale1.parse(localDate1).toString();
Log.v("@@@WWW","in Spanish: "+dateInSpanish);
```

Error

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Miércoles, 04 Octubre 2017 12:00 PM" (at offset 33)
```

Comment: what is the value of `getString(R.string.jom_events_date_input_format_12_hrs)`

Comment: EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm a, when i parse englisn date it works perfectly though

Comment: my default Locale is also "es"

Comment: works fine for me when I replace the `R.string` with your real format

Comment: what can be a cause , It worked for me when replace spanish date with english date and english locale respectively

Comment: double check the value of `R.string.jom_events_date_input_format_12_hrs`

Comment: The problem is related to "PM". You might try to replace it by "p. m." or similar (taken from CLDR-repository in version v30) before parsing.

Comment: @MenoHochschild I changed it but same error

Comment: Can you please debug the expression `new DateFormatSymbols(spanishLocale).getAmPmStrings()` and show its content?

Comment: @MenoHochschild: It gives me{ a. m.
p. m.}

Comment: Then parsing should work with "p. m." instead of "PM" in your input provided that your pattern is really "EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm a" and you use lenient parsing (case-insensitive). Keep in mind that your error message points to the offset 33, the location of "PM"-part.

Comment: @PratikVyas you can check below answer.

Comment: @Chetan Joshi I already checked it earlier but something was wrong

Comment: @MenoHochschild changing to "p. m." actually worked it is not throwing an error, Thanks .

Comment: @MenoHochschild but now it is converting the date into English I want to show it in Spanish only.

Comment: The only "formatting" code in your posted example (after parsing) is only calling the `toString()`-method of `java.util.Date` (which is of course in English and uses your system zone). You need an extra formatter to print your parsed result in Spanish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Just for the record:*

You have fortunately posted your error message which points to the offset 33 (that is the position of "PM" in your input). So we can state:

**Your problem is related to device-dependent localization data** (or OS-dependent), here the concrete data for the Spanish representation of AM/PM. In old versions of CLDR-unicode repository (industry standard as common source for many Java-, C#- or Android distributions), the data "AM" and "PM" were used but in newer versions it uses "a. m." or "p. m." for Spanish.

So in case of mismatch between your input to be parsed (containing "PM") and the real i18n-data you have, I recommend as pragmatic solution string preprocessing:

```
String input = "Miércoles, 04 Octubre 2017 12:00 PM";
input = input.replace("PM", "p. m.");
// now parse your input with Spanish locale and the appropriate pattern
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check you spelling on this line

```
String localDate1="Miércoles, 04 Octubre 2017 12:00 PM";
```

change **October** instead of **Octubre** and also check this **Miércoles**

Comment: it is actually server generated date , and google translate translate it to Wednesday, 04 October 2017 12:00 PM

Comment: The month name and the weekday-name are okay for Spanish (leaving aside the fact that it would rather not be capitalized but the parser is not case-sensitive - lenient by default).

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code for your reference::

This code converts:--- 
miércoles, 04 octubre 2017 12:00 AM
to
Wed Oct 04 00:00:00 IST 2017

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
        //Wednesday, October 4, 2017
        String dateInString = "4-Oct-2017";
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);

        SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm aaaa", new Locale("es", "ES"));
        String fecha = formato.format(date);
        System.out.println(fecha);

        String localDate1 = fecha;
        Locale spanishLocale = new Locale("es", "ES");
        String pattern = "E, dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm aaaa";
        SimpleDateFormat spanishLocale1 = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, spanishLocale);
        String dateInSpanish = spanishLocale1.parse(localDate1).toString();
        System.out.println(dateInSpanish);
    }
}
```